# Most efficient way to get sorted indices based on two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

How can i get the sorted indices of a numpy array (distance), only considering certain indices from another numpy array (val).

For example, consider the two numpy arrays val and distance below:

```
val = np.array([[10, 0,  0,  0,  0],
                [0,  0,  10, 0,  10],
                [0,  10, 10, 0,  0],
                [0,  0,  0,  10, 0],
                [0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])


distance = np.array([[4, 3, 2, 3, 4],
                     [3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                     [2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
                     [3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                     [4, 3, 2, 3, 4]])
```

the distances where val == 10 are 4, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2.  I would like to get these sorted to be 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 and return the respective indices from distance array.

Returning something like:

```
(array([2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0], dtype=int64), array([2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0], dtype=int64))
```

or:

```
(array([2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0], dtype=int64), array([2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0], dtype=int64))
```

since the second and third element both have distance '1', so i guess the indices can be interchangable.

Tried using combinations of `np.where, np.argsort, np.argpartition,  np.unravel_index` but cant seem to get it working right

Comment: So what's the final expected output?

Comment: Divakar, i updated the question.  Yakym, that only returns the distances (its values) not the indices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way with `masking` -

```
In [20]: mask = val==10

In [21]: np.argwhere(mask)[distance[mask].argsort()]
Out[21]: 
array([[2, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [0, 0]])
```